# Check for update - what is the best way to take the last version

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have `Winforms` application and i want to add the option `Check for update` so the user just click on specific `button` and the application will read specific folder in the local network and run the latest version (if exist).
Currently the is how my versions order:

```
MyApplication_1.0.18
MyApplication_1.0.19
MyApplication_1.0.20
MyApplication_1.0.21
MyApplication_1.0.22
.
.
.
```

I know i can search for `LastCreationTime`, `LastModified`... 
Maybe the best option is to compare strings ?

Comment: please show the code that populates this list.

Comment: You can check the assembly version or file version of your exe.

Comment: This list is my versions in specific folder, i am not populate this via code, after i have new version i am build exe file and manually adding the new version into this folder

Comment: simplest solution is, keep a text file in that network folder, and store the folder name of the latest version in that file. So clients have to just read this file and go to that version (in case the current version is different). I see two benefits here 1. For some reason, if you decided to stop the distribution, simply clear the content in that text file. 2. If there are any malfunction with your current version, you can force all your clients to load the prev. version by storing that folder name in that file.